# can't find csv template when trying to download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, export

show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "CSV", patient_record_path(format: "csv") %>
```

record_controller.rb

```
def show

    @data_filtered = PatientData.new(:data => getDataFromURL)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @data_filtered.to_csv }
    end
end
```

patient_data.rb (model)

```
def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate({}) do |csv|
        csv << data.first.keys
        data.each do |hash|
           csv << hash.values
        end
    end
```

end

When I click the CSV link to export this I get the error.  I have required 'csv'
This is the guide I followed http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast

Template is missing

Missing template patient_record/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:csv], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/samantha.klonaris/RubymineProjects/intermediate_form_reader/app/views"

Comment: Why is to_csv a class level method?

Comment: im not quite sure! I followed the tutorial that posted

Comment: do you have corresponding route for `patient_record_path` in routes.rb ?

Comment: and like Vimsha i am wondering too, how class level method `self.to_csv` can be applied to this model instance `PatientData.new` without error? there is something you not tell us =)

Answer (score 0):

In the RailsCast tutorial you referenced, `products_path` corresponded to ProductsController with an action of `index`. Ryan showed you how he defined `ProductsController#index` to respond to csv.

In your case, you've invoked `patient_record_path` which typically maps to `PatientRecordsController` with an action of `show` and an argument specifying which patient. You've showed us a `show` method definition, but it's contained in a file called `record_controller.rb` which is not the normal naming for a `PatientRecordsController` class definition. The error suggests that you have a separate `PatientRecordsController` class with a `show` definition, but which is defaulting to rendering the corresponding show template.

I believe there are problems with your `to_csv` invocation as other commenters have mentioned, but I don't think you're getting to that code at this point.